# Google Map v3 auto refresh Markers only

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Google Maps V3 to display some pins. I want to be able to refresh markers without affecting where you're at on the map or the zoom level. I want the markers to be updated every x seconds.

How would I go about doing this? I don't have that much experience with jQuery/ajax.

A working example of my map is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/dLWNc/

```
 var locations = [
  ['some random info here', -37.8139, 144.9634, 1],
  ['some random info here', 46.0553, 14.5144, 2],
  ['some random info here', -33.7333, 151.0833, 3],
  ['some random info here', 27.9798, -81.731, 4],    ];


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_2385853'), {
  zoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 8, 
  minZoom: 1, 
  streetViewControl: false,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 0),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you want to refresh markers (delete them and then add new ones) or just update their location?

Comment: as far as I am not wrong, all you have to do is overwrite locations array with new data

Comment: To make changes to existing `locations` you will need to arrange for each one to have a unique id, by which it can be addressed. The ids will need to be generated by the server. If you can't do this, then you will have to replace all `locations` (though not necessarily all the corresponding Markers) at every iteration.

Comment: As long as (a) your 1 - 4 are ids and not just indexes and (b) the server can always address each location (hence the associated Marker) via the same unique id on every occasion, then you have the basis for making selective updates, rather than total replacement. Selective updates will require more programming effort, so if the number of locations is small, it is maybe more realistic to opt for total replacement.

Comment: Daniel, yes, on the assumption that only a handful of markers will be affected at each iteration, then for 2000 markers you should definitely perform selective updates. What you say about id generation is good. Existing markers can always be re-addressed by the same id, and new markers will receive a new previously unallocated id - perfect. I've not got time to help with the code right now but will look in later today (in several hours).

Comment: Now the ground-rules are established, maybe @Pawel_W will be able to help sooner than I.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, I've got something working - largely a heavy refactoring of your original code - you will recognize various chunks.

```
$(function() {
    var locations = {};//A repository for markers (and the data from which they were constructed).

    //initial dataset for markers
    var locs = {
        1: { info:'11111. Some random info here', lat:-37.8139, lng:144.9634 },
        2: { info:'22222. Some random info here', lat:46.0553, lng:14.5144 },
        3: { info:'33333. Some random info here', lat:-33.7333, lng:151.0833 },
        4: { info:'44444. Some random info here', lat:27.9798, lng:-81.731 }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_2385853'), {
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 8,
        minZoom: 1,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var auto_remove = true;//When true, markers for all unreported locs will be removed.

function setMarkers(locObj) {
    if(auto_remove) {
        //Remove markers for all unreported locs, and the corrsponding locations entry.
        $.each(locations, function(key) {
            if(!locObj[key]) {
                if(locations[key].marker) {
                    locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
                }
                delete locations[key];
            }
        });
    }

        $.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
            if(!locations[key] && loc.lat!==undefined && loc.lng!==undefined) {
                //Marker has not yet been made (and there's enough data to create one).

                //Create marker
                loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
                    map: map
                });

                //Attach click listener to marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(loc.marker, 'click', (function(key) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
                        infowindow.open(map, locations[key].marker);
                    }
                })(key));

                //Remember loc in the `locations` so its info can be displayed and so its marker can be deleted.
                locations[key] = loc;
            }
            else if(locations[key] && loc.remove) {
                //Remove marker from map
                if(locations[key].marker) {
                    locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
                }
                //Remove element from `locations`
                delete locations[key];
            }
            else if(locations[key]) {
                //Update the previous data object with the latest data.
                $.extend(locations[key], loc);
                if(loc.lat!==undefined && loc.lng!==undefined) {
                    //Update marker position (maybe not necessary but doesn't hurt).
                    locations[key].marker.setPosition(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng)
                    );
                }
                //locations[key].info looks after itself.
            }
        });
    }

    var ajaxObj = {//Object to save cluttering the namespace.
        options: {
            url: "........",//The resource that delivers loc data.
            dataType: "json"//The type of data tp be returned by the server.
        },
        delay: 10000,//(milliseconds) the interval between successive gets.
        errorCount: 0,//running total of ajax errors.
        errorThreshold: 5,//the number of ajax errors beyond which the get cycle should cease.
        ticker: null,//setTimeout reference - allows the get cycle to be cancelled with clearTimeout(ajaxObj.ticker);
        get: function() { //a function which initiates 
            if(ajaxObj.errorCount < ajaxObj.errorThreshold) {
                ajaxObj.ticker = setTimeout(getMarkerData, ajaxObj.delay);
            }
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            ajaxObj.errorCount++;
        }
    };

    //Ajax master routine
    function getMarkerData() {
        $.ajax(ajaxObj.options)
          .done(setMarkers) //fires when ajax returns successfully
          .fail(ajaxObj.fail) //fires when an ajax error occurs
          .always(ajaxObj.get); //fires after ajax success or ajax error
    }

    setMarkers(locs);//Create markers from the initial dataset served with the document.
    //ajaxObj.get();//Start the get cycle.

    // *******************
    //test: simulated ajax
    /*
    var testLocs = {
        1: { info:'1. New Random info and new position', lat:-37, lng:124.9634 },//update info and position and 
        2: { lat:70, lng:14.5144 },//update position
        3: { info:'3. New Random info' },//update info
        4: { remove: true },//remove marker
        5: { info:'55555. Added', lat:-37, lng:0 }//add new marker
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
        setMarkers(testLocs);
    }, ajaxObj.delay);
    */
    // *******************
});
```

At the bottom of the code, you'll find a `testLocs` dataset, demonstrating the range of possibilities for adding/removing/updating markers after the initial dataset has been applied.

I've not tested the ajax fully, but have simulated it with the `testLocs` dataset.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvcbt/)**

After 10 seconds, `testLocs` will be applied and you will see various changes to the markers (and the info displayed in the infowindow). Note in particular that update data doesn't need to be complete - just specify the changes.

You will need to arrange for your server to :

- build the initial dataset, following my `locs` example.
- return JSON-encoded datasets, following the general format of my `testLocs` example.

### EDIT 1

I have included all the client-side code necessary for fetching new datasets. All you need to do is :

- create a server-side script (eg. "get_markers.php") which returns a json-encoded dataset of the right format (as already exaplined).
- edit the line `url: "........",` to point to the server-side script, eg `url: "get_markers.php"`.
- activate the cyclic ajax process by uncommenting the line `ajaxObj.get();`.
- ensure the "simulated ajax" code block is commented out or removed.

### EDIT 2

I have added a boolean "behavioural switch" named `auto_remove`. When set to true, a small additional block of code will run, causing all markers for unreported locs to be removed.

This will allow you to report all *active* markers at every iteration. Removals will happen automatically, without needing to actively command them.

The code which responds to `{ remove: true }` is still in place, so (with `auto_remove` set to `false`) removals can be expressly commanded if you ever need to do so.

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvcbt/1/)**

### EDIT 3

The PHP script should build an array of the following form :

```
<%php
$testLocs = array(
    'loc1' => array( 'info' => '1. New Random info and new position', 'lat' => 0, 'lng' => 144.9634 ),
    'loc2' => array( 'lat'  => 0, 'lng' => 14.5144 ),
    'loc3' => array( 'info' => '3. New Random info' ),
    'loc5' => array( 'info' => '55555. Added', 'lat' => 0, 'lng' => 60 )
);
echo json_encode($testLocs);
exit();
%>
```

I'm not sure whether PHP will handle numeric keys. If not, then try strings, `'1'`, `'2'` etc. It's probably safest to give all keys an alphabetic prefix, eg. `'loc1'`, `'loc2'` etc. Whatever you choose to do, make sure the keys in the javascript `locs` object are of the same type and composition.

Comment: I would like as if I want to update specific markers depends on json object id and remain other markers position.

Comment: Isn't it **<?php**, and not **<%php**?

Comment: Somehow I never got the php part to work.. I see the php being pulled from the server but it doesn't update the markers (just removes all). I also put the php output as a test.json and again, i see it pulled from the webserver as mime type json but nothing happens in the map. It doesn't display any errors in the console.