# Add markercluster Google Maps V3

Tags: marker, markerclusterer

I using code like in this page. how can I add marker cluster?

Thanks.

[[Google Map v3 auto refresh Markers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771422/google-map-v3-auto-refresh-markers-only][1])

Answer (score 0):

Sample script...

```
$(function() {
    var locations = {};//A repository for markers (and the data from which they were constructed).

    //initial dataset for markers
    var locs = {
        1: { info:'11111. Some random info here', lat:-37.8139, lng:144.9634 },
        2: { info:'22222. Some random info here', lat:46.0553, lng:14.5144 },
        3: { info:'33333. Some random info here', lat:-33.7333, lng:151.0833 },
        4: { info:'44444. Some random info here', lat:27.9798, lng:-81.731 }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_2385853'), {
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 8,
        minZoom: 1,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var auto_remove = true;//When true, markers for all unreported locs will be removed.

function setMarkers(locObj) {
    if(auto_remove) {
        //Remove markers for all unreported locs, and the corrsponding locations entry.
        $.each(locations, function(key) {
            if(!locObj[key]) {
                if(locations[key].marker) {
                    locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
                }
                delete locations[key];
            }
        });
    }

        $.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
            if(!locations[key] && loc.lat!==undefined && loc.lng!==undefined) {
                //Marker has not yet been made (and there's enough data to create one).

                //Create marker
                loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
                    map: map
                });

                //Attach click listener to marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(loc.marker, 'click', (function(key) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
                        infowindow.open(map, locations[key].marker);
                    }
                })(key));

                //Remember loc in the `locations` so its info can be displayed and so its marker can be deleted.
                locations[key] = loc;
            }
            else if(locations[key] && loc.remove) {
                //Remove marker from map
                if(locations[key].marker) {
                    locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
                }
                //Remove element from `locations`
                delete locations[key];
            }
            else if(locations[key]) {
                //Update the previous data object with the latest data.
                $.extend(locations[key], loc);
                if(loc.lat!==undefined && loc.lng!==undefined) {
                    //Update marker position (maybe not necessary but doesn't hurt).
                    locations[key].marker.setPosition(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng)
                    );
                }
                //locations[key].info looks after itself.
            }
        });
    }

    var ajaxObj = {//Object to save cluttering the namespace.
        options: {
            url: "........",//The resource that delivers loc data.
            dataType: "json"//The type of data tp be returned by the server.
        },
        delay: 10000,//(milliseconds) the interval between successive gets.
        errorCount: 0,//running total of ajax errors.
        errorThreshold: 5,//the number of ajax errors beyond which the get cycle should cease.
        ticker: null,//setTimeout reference - allows the get cycle to be cancelled with clearTimeout(ajaxObj.ticker);
        get: function() { //a function which initiates 
            if(ajaxObj.errorCount < ajaxObj.errorThreshold) {
                ajaxObj.ticker = setTimeout(getMarkerData, ajaxObj.delay);
            }
        },
        fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            ajaxObj.errorCount++;
        }
    };

    //Ajax master routine
    function getMarkerData() {
        $.ajax(ajaxObj.options)
          .done(setMarkers) //fires when ajax returns successfully
          .fail(ajaxObj.fail) //fires when an ajax error occurs
          .always(ajaxObj.get); //fires after ajax success or ajax error
    }

    setMarkers(locs);//Create markers from the initial dataset served with the document.
    //ajaxObj.get();//Start the get cycle.

    // *******************
    //test: simulated ajax
    /*
    var testLocs = {
        1: { info:'1. New Random info and new position', lat:-37, lng:124.9634 },//update info and position and 
        2: { lat:70, lng:14.5144 },//update position
        3: { info:'3. New Random info' },//update info
        4: { remove: true },//remove marker
        5: { info:'55555. Added', lat:-37, lng:0 }//add new marker
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
        setMarkers(testLocs);
    }, ajaxObj.delay);
    */
    // *******************
});
```